# WebStorm type checking with type defined in an IIFE

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

I often define a class-like data/type structure in js, such as:

```
/**
 * @param {string} d
 * @constructor
 */
function MyType(d) {

    /**
     * @param {string} a
     * @param {string} [b]
     */
    this.search = function (a, b) {};
}
```

I use jsdoc to document my types, and WebStorm / PhpStorm / IntelliJ usually does a great job with autocomplete and warning me if if I forgot a function arg etc...

But, this doesn't work so well when I define my type inside of an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), like so

```
var MyType = (function () {

    /**
     * @param {string} d
     * @constructor
     */
    function MyType(d) {

        /**
         * @param {string} a
         * @param {string} [b]
         */
        this.search = function (a, b) {};
    }

    return MyType;
})();
```

The problem is I won't get proper warnings when I forget function args. For example the following should give me squiggly lines/warnings for both lines, letting me know I'm missing arguments.

```
var mt = new MyType();
mt.search();
```

It works perfectly if I don't define my type inside the IIFE, but I can't make it work perfectly with it. I've tried a few different things, which seem to have various levels of success, but none work perfect.

If I do

```
var MyType = (function () {
   ...
   return MyType;
})();
var mt = new MyType();
mt.search();
```

...the problem is I don't get warned about missing a constructor arg, although it does correctly warn me about the missing `search()` arg. Also, <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on MyType takes me to the `var MyType` line, when ideally it should take me to the orig function definition.

If I do

```
/** @var {MyType} window.MyType */
window.MyType = (function () {
   ...
   return MyType;
})();
var mt = new MyType();
mt.search();
```

...then I do get proper warnings about missing constructor arg, and <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on MyType works properly, by I don't get a warning about missing args on the `.search()` call, and <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on search doesn't work right.

**Is there a way to make this work better when using IIFE's?** Ideally, I'd prefer a method that doesn't resort to global state/definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is tracked as [WEB-20246](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20246); please follow it for updates